# Одно UIView на всех UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Необходимо создать `UIView`, которое будет подвязано ко всем `UIViewController`, с возможностью изменения этого `UIView` во всех контроллерах.

Пробывал подвязывать к

`UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];`

Но элемент не меняется в других окнах.

Comment: Можете попробовать создать xib, и в каждом контроллерe и менять его.

Comment: Если возможно, можете подробнее описать решение ?

Comment: имеется ввиду, что у каждого контроллера self.view будет один и тот же объект, или просто сделать вью, который будет доступен глобально для всех контроллеров приложения?

Comment: Хотелось бы один объект использовать... У меня есть основной контроллер от которого наследуются все остальные, я могу там создать это вью, но тогда надо как-то сделать что бы это вью всегда с самого верха (в плане слоев)

Comment: короче вам надо, чтоб у каждого контроллера в иерархии был один и тот же вью?

Comment: Да, и что бы из любого контроллера я этот вью мог изменить, волнует только альфа.

Comment: Можно этот xib зарегистрироватьи в том контроллеры котором вам нужно и меняйте alfa. Информацию легко найдете как зарегистри-ровать там нет ничего сложного.

Comment: ну два варианта, поскольку один и тот же вью не может одновременно иметь несколько superView, то иметь один и тот же везде сразу не получится. 1) хранить вью где то (например в синглтоне), и чтобы каждый контроллер у себя во viewWillAppear дергал этот вью себе. 2) иметь копию этого вью, везде где надо, и хранить только альфу; и тогда каждый контроллер во viewWillAppear должен применять эту альфу к своей копии вью

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение !